# How to embed or nest row with tab inbootstrap?

Tags: drop-down-menu, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I have following snippet. I want to align or ember tab and dropdown menu inside the navtab class. but, its coming out of it. Please help to resolve the problem.

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs customtab" id="mynav">
            <li class="dropdown custom-font-dd">
                <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
                  <li><a href="#dropdown1" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Auto</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown2" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Homeowners</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown3" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">Renters</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown4" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">more...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown custom-font-dd">
                <a href="#" id="myTabDrop2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Your Policy<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop2">
                  <li><a href="#dropdown1" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tab">Log In</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown2" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tab">Sign up</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown3" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tab">View policy</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown4" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tab">Print ID card</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown custom-font-dd">
                <a href="#" id="myTabDrop3" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Claims<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
                  <li><a href="#dropdown1" tabindex="1" data-toggle="tab">File a new claim</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown2" tabindex="1" data-toggle="tab">View a claim status</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown3" tabindex="1" data-toggle="tab">Forms</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#dropdown4" tabindex="1" data-toggle="tab">FAQs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </div>![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: `<li>` should be contained in `<ul>`, not `div`. Seems to work fine here: http://bootply.com/92756 Explain what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is there any way I can customize the dropdown other than color etc?